# Do these sentences mean different things?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

- I desire to do this
- Doing this is very interesting to me

Web searches provide no clear answer

Comment: They are completely different.  Why would you suppose there is any similarity?   The words are all different, so I can see no connection between the sentences.  Have you looked at the meaning of "desire".  Have you looked at the meaning of "interesting".  They have completely different meanings.  What context are you hoping to use these sentence in?

Comment: Very common to construct sentences that are starkly different but with identical meaning. Recommended action is edit your comments to reflect this.

Comment: I'll allow the OP to clarify their question with the reason that they suppose that there is any relationship in meaning.  I see these as no more related than any two sentences about the same "thing".  I think the OP should establish, by means of a dictionary the difference in the meaning of the words.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These have related but distinct meanings.

Desire may be used to indicate want, eg "I desire a thing" which means "I want a thing".

Interesting may be used to describe a thing, eg "a thing is interesting" which means "I am interested in a thing".

They have different meanings because "desire" refers to how the person feels and "interesting" describes the thing.

Comment: Do these sentences have different meanings

Comment: I've edited the comment to reflect the different meanings

Answer (score -1):

"I desire to do this" means you haven't done it and you would like to try, whereas "Doing this is very interesting to me" implies that you've already done it a lot and you like doing it.

Comment: 'I desire to do this today' could be said about something you had done every day for 10 years.